# Fonts are showing up in Windows/Font folder but not in Font Settings

Tags: windows-10, fonts

I downloaded Roboto Mono from Google Fonts and *installed them on Windows 10*. They were showing in *Font Settings* and I was using them in *VScode*. After laptop reboot VScode is not picking them up anymore and they are not in *Font Settings*:

[image: Font Settings]

But they are still showing in *Windows/Font folder*:

[image: Windows Font folder]

[image: Fonts installed]

Why is that?

Comment: try reinstaling the fonts once again. They should show up.

Comment: I did, but same thing happens again after reboot.

Comment: Hi! I have this issue as well. Have you managed to solve it?

Comment: @Cerberus hi, no I didn't. I didn't figure out what is wrong and to be honest haven't installed new fonts in a while.

Comment: @cikatomo: OK understandable. What I ended up doing: I used Everything to find that there was an invisibile font file in the Fonts folder with with a suffix _1.tff/some other extension (don't remember), which I deleted. Then Windows still said it was already installed, when I wanted to install it. I then found an entry in the Registry which I deleted: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts\[name of problem font]`. After that, Windows no longer said it was already installed. I rebooted, installed, rebooted twice. Working well so far (we'll see for how long...).

Comment: @Cerberus so you fiddled with registry? Ok thanks, I'll keep that in mind if I ever experience font problem again